# PHP - force first letter upppercase, others lowercase, with an uppercase exception

Tags: php

I have a PHP function that is supposed to make the first letter of each word uppercase and all other letters lowercase. By default, in my function an exception is made if all letters of a word are uppercase, in which case that word should be left all uppercase. UNLESS I pass in true for the 2nd param (`$disallowAllUppercase`) -- in which case all caps won't be allowed (the first letter of each word forced caps, all other letters forced lowercase).

I got most of the following function from a stack overflow post but cannot remember where. It mostly works correctly, but I found a case where it falls down:

```
function NormalizeWords($str, $disallowAllUppercase = false){
    $parts = explode(' ', $str);

    if($disallowAllUppercase){
        $result = array_map(function($x){
            return ucwords(strtolower($x));
        }, $parts);
    }else{
        $result = array_map(function($x){
            if (!ctype_upper($x)) {
                return ucwords(strtolower($x));
            }
            return $x;
        }, $parts);
    }

    return implode(' ', $result);
}
function writeme($str){
    echo $str . "<br>";
}
```

When I run the following:

```
writeme(NormalizeWords("ABC1"));
writeme(NormalizeWords("ABC1", true));
writeme(NormalizeWords("ABC1", false));
```

...I get the following results:

```
Abc1
Abc1
Abc1
```

Expected results:

```
ABC1
Abc1
ABC1
```

In summary, if there is only 1 word and that word contains a number, it doesn't work.

What changes do I need to make to this function to get it to work correctly in all cases?

Comment: `preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]$/', $x) > 0`?

Comment: A regular expression is unnecessary overhead for this check.  `[0-9]` is more simply written as `\d` and the `> 0` is not needed.

Comment: @mickmackusa dupe seems to work fine for this: https://3v4l.org/3peh6

Comment: I must have tested wrong.  Please rehammer. @Nick

Comment: @mickmackusa done. btw you could have tagged me in these comments (since I posted an answer) instead of on the other question.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure about that.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/3peh6 works great - THANK YOU!